# Syntax structure of filter method in javascript determines result

Tags: javascript, algorithm, syntax

I was working on a coding problem and I came across something that's throwing me for a loop(no pun intended). It's fairly simple, but I'm hoping for clarity from someone with more experience.

I was trying to solve it as such, but it wasn't working (I know it isn't necessary to check for zero, but I was just messing around and found this "quirk")

```
 const filter_list = (l) => {
      return l.filter(item => {
        if(typeof item === 'number' || item === 0) {
          return item;
      }
   })
 }
```

It wasn't passing the tests, but when it's written like this, it passes all the tests:

```
const filter_list = (l) => l.filter(item => typeof item === 'number' || item === 0);
```

What is it about the second version that makes it pass the tests? There's a syntax difference, but the logic seems like it's the same to me.

Comment: You didn't write anything about the actual problem you're solving

Comment: In the first one you're returning `item`. In the second one you're returning the result of the comparison.

Comment: So they're not equivalent.

Comment: The first one returns the item when the condition is true, or undefined when it's not. The second returns the condition itself. This is relevant when the condition is true but the item is falsy (ie, the item is 0)

Comment: @Barmar  Okay, I understand now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GuerricP Sorry you didn't understand the question. I'll word it better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic isn't the same. In the first version you have `return item;`, you don't return `item` in the second version. The second version returns the condition result.

The second version is equivalent to this:

```
const filter_list = (l) => {
  return l.filter(item => {
    return typeof item === 'number' || item === 0;
  })
}
```

And if you want to abbreviate the first function, it would be:

```
const filter_list = (l) => l.filter(item => typeof item === 'number' || item === 0 ? item : undefined);
```

Your condition logic also doesn't make much sense. It will be true for all numbers, so adding `|| item === 0` won't change the result. I suspect you meant `&&`. But since you're using strict equality, there's no need to test the type -- nothing but a number can be strictly equal to `0`.

Comment: I understand that it's not necessary to check for zero. It was just something I was messing around with to see what happens. I'm glad I did because I learned something new here. Thanks.